# Probability of sparse spectrum

Tags: sampling, references, sparse, probability-inequalities, fourier-transform

Consider a vector $v$ such that $v \sim \mathrm{Unif}(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})$, the uniform distribution on the unit sphere in $d$ dimensions.

**Question**: is there an upper bound on the probability that $v$ has a sparse spectrum? (e.g. $\mathbb{P}\left( |\mathrm{supp}(\hat{v})| \leq \sqrt{d}\right)$, where $\hat{v}$ is the DFT of $v$)? Any pointers to references are more than welcome.

Comment: What is g hat for?

Comment: @CarlosCampos: Sorry, that was a typo. $\hat{v}$ is the DFT of the vector $v$.